# Drag down Formula to LastRow VBA

Tags: vba

check my code below: I am trying to drag down a formula to the LastRow and I can not, it gives me an error at my range. Any ideas why? What am I doing wrong?

```
Sub Mix()
'
' Mix Macro
'
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Range("Q35").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(RC[-13],RC[-12])"
    Lastrow = Worksheets("NewForecast").Range("E" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("Q" & Lastrow), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

Any idea what is going on? Tks!

Comment: You have 3 lines with the word `Range`. Which one are you referring to by the phrase "at my range"? Also, if you have an error message, what is the code and what does it say?

Comment: The last line and the error is: Run time error '1004' : "AutoFill method of Range class failed".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195345.aspx) says (about the parameter `Destination`) "The cells to be filled. The destination must include the source range." Your destination doesn't include the source range. I think that you want:

```
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("Q35:Q" & Lastrow), Type:=xlFillDefault
```